# How to plot Planckian locus in xyY color space employing APIs in the Matlab or OpenCV library?

Tags: matlab, opencv, colors

I made the conversion from RBG color space into the 1931 **CIE xyY** color space of a picture in Matlab. And I applied a double logarithmic (log–log) transformation (log(x/y),log(z/y), with x, y and z, the xyY color model bands) of each pixels of the image, and plotted the result (see the figure).

Now, I want to add a Planckian locus to the figure, but I do not know how. I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this problem. Thank you in advance. Merry Chrismas![image]

Comment: As far as I know, CIE 1931 defines absolute color coordinates X,Y, and Z, and from them relative color coordinates x and y. What is z, and why are you plotting logarithms of ratios? This way effectively you transform into yet another color space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia page [Planckian locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus) explains how to compute CIE 1931 xy color coordinates exactly. It also provides the following formulas based on a cubic spline approximation

[image: x_c]

[image: y_c]

and quotes [US patent 2003095138](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=7024034&KC=&FT=E&locale=en_EP) as the source.